# XSL Basics: showing value of a boolean?

Tags: xslt, boolean

When I have this in xsl:

```
<xsl:choose>
  <xsl:when test="something > 0">
    <xsl:variable name="myVar" select="true()"/>
  </xsl:when>
  <xsl:otherwise>
    <xsl:variable name="myVar" select="false()"/>
  </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

How can I then print out the value of "myVar"? Or more importantly, how can I use this boolean in another choose statement?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
<xsl:choose>
  <xsl:when test="something > 0">
    <xsl:variable name="myVar" select="true()"/>
  </xsl:when>
  <xsl:otherwise>
    <xsl:variable name="myVar" select="false()"/>
  </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

**This is quite wrong and useless, because the variable `$myVar` goes out of scope immediately**.

One correct way to conditionally assign to the variable is:

```
<xsl:variable name="myVar">
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="something > 0">1</xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>0</xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:variable>
```

**However, you really don't need this  -- much simpler is**:

```
<xsl:variable name="myVar" select="something > 0"/>
```

> ```
> How can I then print out the value of "myVar"?
> ```

**Use**:

```
<xsl:value-of select="$myVar"/>
```

> Or more importantly, how can I use this boolean in another choose
>   statement?

**Here is a simple example:**

```
<xsl:choose>
  <xsl:when test="$myVar">
   <!-- Do something -->
  </xsl:when>
  <xsl:otherwise>
   <!-- Do something else -->
  </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

**And here is a complete example**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*/*">
  <xsl:variable name="vNonNegative" select=". >= 0"/>

  <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>: <xsl:text/>

  <xsl:choose>
   <xsl:when test="$vNonNegative">Above zero</xsl:when>
   <xsl:otherwise>Below zero</xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on the following XML document**:

```
<temps>
 <Monday>-2</Monday>
 <Tuesday>3</Tuesday>
</temps>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
 Monday: Below zero
 Tuesday: Above zero
```

Comment: Thank you, everything I asked for! Sorry about the noobish question, I just didn't find this that intuitive at first!

Comment: If you don't mind answering this, is there a way to do an if not statement in xsl? I read somewhere to put not() around your statement but that didn't seem to work for me! Thanks again for the answer on here though :)

Comment: @ing0: Of course: `<xsl:if test="not(someCondition)"> <!-- Do whatever necessary here --></xsl:if>` . However, it is in the spirit of XSLT to avoid explicit conditional logic as this as much as possible and to use template pattern matching instead: `<xsl:template match="someName[not(someCondition)]"> <!-- Whatever necessary processing here  --> </xsl:template>` Do note thatthere is no explicit `<xsl:if>` at all in this last example.

Comment: Thanks so much! All makes sense now! :)

Comment: Minor typo: within "Here is a simple example:" above the second "<xsl:choose>" should actually be "</xsl:choose>".

Comment: @GregTrevellick, Good catch, fixed now!